# How can I get this dropdown menu to display the dropdown options from a table heading cell?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a dropdown menu inside an HTML table heading cell, however the menu options do not appear when the button is clicked. N.B. the HTML table is inside PHP tags as I'm populating the table from a database.

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<th>Item</th> <th>Expiry</th> <th>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Location</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fridge</a></li>
<li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Freezer</a></li>
<li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Pullout Cupboard</a></li>
</ul>
</div> </th> <th>Remove</th>';
```

I'm fairly new to programming and have not yet used JavaScript however I see that may be the way to go.

Edit: as requested here is the only CSS I have that affects this code

```
.databaseTable th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
```

Solved! I had to add a jquery.js and bootstrap.js script.

Comment: it seems to be working fine. The output looked like this http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5526/

Are you sure you included `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css` ?

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, glad it's working for you! I haven't included jquery.js or bootstrap.js. Do they go in the refs at the top of the HTML doc with the bootstrap.css?

Comment: this is how your page should roughly look like http://i.imgur.com/TaA0BmG.png

Comment: Thanks very much! It's all working :-D